# Script for virtualdub to cut videos

Tags: virtualdub

I have videos I would like to process to remove x secondes at their beginning. Since I have around 140 videos I started to write a script to do so but... it does not work !

My present script is :

```
VirtualDub.audio.SetSource(1);
VirtualDub.audio.SetMode(0);
VirtualDub.audio.SetInterleave(1,500,1,0,0);
VirtualDub.audio.SetClipMode(1,1);
VirtualDub.audio.SetEditMode(1);
VirtualDub.audio.SetConversion(0,0,0,0,0);
VirtualDub.audio.SetVolume();
VirtualDub.audio.SetCompression();
VirtualDub.audio.EnableFilterGraph(0);
VirtualDub.video.SetInputFormat(0);
VirtualDub.video.SetOutputFormat(7);
VirtualDub.video.SetMode(3);
VirtualDub.video.SetSmartRendering(0);
VirtualDub.video.SetPreserveEmptyFrames(0);
VirtualDub.video.SetFrameRate2(15,1,1);
VirtualDub.video.SetRange(600000,290000);
VirtualDub.video.SetIVTC(0, 0, 0, 0);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompression(0x6376736d,0,8000,0);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompData(4,"SwAAAA==");
VirtualDub.video.filters.Clear();
VirtualDub.audio.filters.Clear();
```

As you may note I also change framerate and I compress the video.

My command-line is:
"C:\Program Files\VirtualDub-1.10.4\VirtualDub.exe" /s "C:\Users...\framerate.vdscript" /c /b "C:\Users...\video" "C:\Users...\output" /r /x

This allows me to process all videos in "C:\Users...\video" folder and to save them in "C:\Users...\output" folder.

Framerate change and compression work perfectly but not the trimming !!!
The puzzling thing is that when I open one of the video in VDub then i load the script it actually defines a range and processes it exactly as I want !!!

An additional question is how I could define specific starts for each video files (I may change the script opening each file setting range, closing it and have a routine to change range according to each file - not sure it is possible in a script and I don't know how to do so but I didn't check yet).

Any help would be very much appreciated !

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring my second goal (processing several files) using the script below which is a simplified version of the previous one (without audio and seemingly useless things) :

```
VirtualDub.Open("C:/Users/.../File1.avi",0,0);
VirtualDub.video.SetFrameRate2(15,1,1);
VirtualDub.video.SetRange(600000,290000);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompression(0x6376736d,0,8000,0);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompData(4,"SwAAAA==");
VirtualDub.video.filters.Clear();
VirtualDub.SaveAVI("C:/Users/.../Output1.avi");
VirtualDub.Open("C:/Users/.../File2.avi",0,0);
VirtualDub.video.SetFrameRate2(15,1,1);
VirtualDub.video.SetRange(600000,290000);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompression(0x6376736d,0,8000,0);
VirtualDub.video.SetCompData(4,"SwAAAA==");
VirtualDub.video.filters.Clear();
VirtualDub.SaveAVI("C:/Users/.../Output2.avi");
```

And it worked!!!
May be the recursive processing of one folder content was the issue?

Note than moved from the command line to the script the \ in the path have to be changed to /

Cheers,

Xavier